# Continuity of an Integral (Dominated Convergence)

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm doing some reading in analysis, and am having trouble understanding the following idea.

Given an integral $I(v) = \int f(v,w) dw$, we want to show that it's continuous as a function of $v$. 
The source I'm reading says that this follows by Lesbesgue's theorem (I assume the D.C.T.) once we show that $I(v)$ is locally bounded. The function $f$ is continuous in $v$.

I know we need to see that 
$$\lim_{v\to v_0} |I(v) - I(v_0)| = \lim_{v\to v_0} |\int f(v,w)-f(v_0,w) dw| = 0 = \int \lim_{v \to v_0} |f(v_0,w)-f(v,w)| dw, $$ but I don't see how getting a bound $|I(v)| \leq M$ for $v$ near $v_0$ helps with that. You get $\lim_{v\to v_0} |I(v) - I(v_0)| \leq 2M,$ of course, but that doesn't seem like enough.

The measure space is not finite, and there's not a lot of information about $f$ (not known to be bounded, etc).

Any guidance would be appreciated. I think this must be simple, but I'm just not seeing it. Thanks.

---

[Specifically, $w = (y,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $v = (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+$. The function $f$ is 
$$ f(v,w) = f(x,t,y,s) = \frac{\chi_{[0,t]}(s)}{(t-s)^{1/2}}e^{i(x-y)^2/(4t-4s)} F(y,s)$$
where $F$ is a function which I know little about. ]

---

To apply the D.C.T. to this function, I would need an integrable  $g(y,s)$ s.t. 
$$ \frac{\chi_{(0,t_0+\delta)}(s)}{(t_0+\delta - s)^{1/2}}|F(y,s)| \leq g(y,s)$$ for fixed $t_0$ and all $\delta$ sufficiently small. 
This doesn't seem possible, since the L.H.S. of the above approaches infinity as $s \to t_0 + \delta$, so there can't be a dominating function that works for *all* small $\delta$. Is there possibly another Lebesgue's theorem that would be applicable here?

Comment: So it would appear you know $f$ is continuous in $v$ and you need to assume something like integrable in $w$?

Comment: Yes, integrable in $w$.